# Difference Between Request.Cookies["UserID"] and Request.Cookies["UserID"].Value

Tags: asp.net, cookies

here is my sample code.
i m checking the code for null user ID, still it is getting executed....!

```
    if (!IsPostBack == true && Request.Cookies["UserID"] != null)
    {
        string userID = Request.Cookies["UserID"].Value;
        myPageBL.GetFriendRequests(userID); // this can never be null, but is taking null
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Request.Cookies["UserID"] != null should tell you whether the Cookie with name "UserID" exists whereas Request.Cookies["UserID"].Value tells you the actual Value named as "UserID" inside the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

```
Request.Cookies["UserID"]
```

Will return a [HttpCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw640823.aspx) object called "UserID", or null if it doesn't exist.

```
Request.Cookies["UserID"].Value
```

Will return the [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.value.aspx) of the HttpCookie.

So, what could be happening is that the Cookie is there, but the value is empty.

But still, i can't see how the **Value** could be null. string.Emtpy maybe, but not null.

Comment: i have used this code in many places, its only in a few places that i does not work. and sorry i could not understand ur question about string.. its a class System String string ... if i m clear here

Comment: Have a look at the links in my question. The default value for the cookies is a null reference. So you may be creating the cookie, but not setting the value, in which case the value will be null.